Web server refuses connections after some time working on it
I work as a web developer, sometimes i need to create some tiny apps from scratch, so i work with a web based code editor.
My problem comes when sometimes my pc lost connection to the server after working a little time. Browser shows ERR_TIMED_OUT.
So, here comes my investigation:

Every other website out of this server works with no problem, so is not my internet connection.
Every other browser in this computer has the same problem, so it might be my computer.
Using ping command in the console works and the server reply normally, with no lag, so the server is UP and running.
From other computers, in the same LAN network, the website works with no problem, however after some time working, it loses connection too, same symptoms as my computer.
From a cellphone, with mobile connection, the website works normally. So far we can assume that the webserver is ok and working normally.

Now here it gets weird:

If i stop working for some time, my connection to this the website comes alive again.
In the same way, if my computer goes suspended some time, i can work again.

So far i think the web server has some security issue that blocks my ip for some time if i reload the website too many times... However:

Other computer in the LAN network shares the same public IP as mine, but those are able to connect for some time even if my computer can't

So if the server have some IP block feature, how it can block only one computer from the same IP and same network?
Now i'm stuck here... any ideas?

Who runs/manages/administers this server? What sort of connection is there between your computer and this server?

does the site implement any request filtering or dynamic IP restrictions?

does clearing cookies and cache immediately resolve the issue?

This question is not about computer hardware or software, within the scope defined in the help center.

Given what you've told us so far, the most likely cause of this is issues with the server itself. You imply this server is run by your employer and is likely remote to you. If this is the case, the proper path to resolve this is to speak to your employer/the people responsible for running this server.

@music2myear this is a classic VPS with whm and cpanel, connection is optic fiber

@FrankThomas this site has no request filtering or dynamic IP restrictions so far

@Ramhound apache, linux, chrome, php, etc... isn't software?

@quakeglen - I see no mention of any of those software packages in the question body. I believe I voted to migrate this to Serverfault. However, you have not given nothing specific to diagnose your problem. You don't even mention this is a VPS.
